# stop users linking to files in file system from web pages

Tags: file-upload, hyperlink, document-id

We are still working on our sharepoint implementation and have had a requirement come in from the powers that be to stop users linking to file system(network drive) documents from their webpages. Instead the desired behaviour is that users upload their docs into sharepoint and refrence them from there. Is this possible in out of the box sharepoint. If not what are things that i can google/look at in order to try and diagnose the gravity of work required?

Any help or advice is much apreciated?

Thanks

Nicholas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't really be anyway to prevent them from doing so.  However, you could use the suggestion in the answer here: [Regex Query Against FAST Search 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/regex-query-against-fast-search-2010).  That is to create an external processor for the search engine that sets a flag true on the indexed item if content on the page matches a regular expression that identifies a link to a local drive.  Then do search queries on that property to find and correct content that has been linked as such.

Comment: Thanks for the response i thought that this might be a big ask. This will potentially be something that we will have to build into a busines process and mitigate risk through training.

Comment: End user training is ultimately the best solution.  I might suggest that you involve your users in defining your governance policy.  In my experience, if they are involved in creating the rules, they are more likely to follow them.

Comment: Thats a good idea i will feed back your experiences to the higher powers. Again many thanks for sharing your experiences